# FSRM for folder classification by its name

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-server

I'm going to deploy DAC (Dynamic Access Control) and FSRM (File Server Resource Manager) on Server 2012. The primary goal is to dynamically hide sub-folders with specific name (let say, 'Top Secret') for specific users ('Users').

I see that I can create resource property and manually assign it to folder. I can use FSRM to classify files by its contents or by file names or classify specific, pre-defined folders. However, I don't see a way how to classify folder by its name. Is it possible?

If not, any suggestions how to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Since you're so into using acronyms instead of fully spelling out the components you're using, try this one: you should look into using ABE.

Comment: I'm sorry for acronyms, I have edited my question. ABE (Access based enumeration), however, is not exactly what I'm looking for because it applies for already existed permissions. I need dynamically set permissions based on the folder name. It's clear how to do this with FILES but unclear how to handle FOLDERS.

Comment: OK. Understood. I thought it might be what you needed, but it looks like it's not. At any rate, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After number of experiments I can conclude that it seems not possible.
Classification works only for files based on their contents and for folders based on their absolute path. File names' patterns can be used only to restrict which files to classify but not as base for classification itself.

Comment: BTW, very strange behavior. So many files that we can't control over their contents (like applications or images). Folder classification based on absolute path seems little sense as we should setup resource permission on these folders again, so why not to set permissions directly. For me, classification based on file and folders name patterns looks like most obvious feature that is absent.